# Is there a way to access the context from everywhere in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to have a global variable that is accessible by any module within my django request without having to pass it around as parameter. Traditionally in other MVCs, I would store it in the request context or session and access the context with something like a "get_current_context" method (which I couldn't find in Django).

Is there something like this, or some other mechanism that will allow me to have a value available from anywhere in the request context?

TIA!

UPDATE: My research has only come up with one viable solution - thread locals (some would argue it's not viable, but there's a pretty active discussion about it, with pros and cons and seems like most people think you should be able to use it in Django, if you do it responsibly).

Comment: Perhaps, but bear in mind that you can have multiple contexts per request, and multiple threads (= multiple requests) running in parallel, which could result in hundreds of active contexts at any point in time so how would it know which context to return?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm talking about being able to access something like the session from anywhere in the code (without having to pass the session variable around).

Comment: Well, by "context", I assumed you meant a `django.template.Context` object, or a subclass thereof, which you'd later use to render a `django.template.Template`. If so, there can be multiple `Context` objects per request if you're rendering multiple `Template` objects, e.g. if you're using custom template tags. If you're using one of Django's built-in class-based views like `TemplateView`, then much of that process is hidden from you. It might help to clarify with a code example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's still not completely clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you might want something like the following.

If you create a piece of middleware in, say...

```
myproject/myapp/middleware/globalrequestmiddleware.py
```

...which looks like this...

```
import thread

class GlobalRequestMiddleware(object):
    _threadmap = {}

    @classmethod
    def get_current_request(cls):
        return cls._threadmap[thread.get_ident()]

    def process_request(self, request):
        self._threadmap[thread.get_ident()] = request

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        try:
            del self._threadmap[thread.get_ident()]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        try:
            del self._threadmap[thread.get_ident()]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return response
```

...then add it into your `settings.py` `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` as the first item in the list...

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'myproject.myapp.middleware.globalrequestmiddleware.GlobalRequestMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

...then you can use it anywhere in the request/response process like this...

```
from myproject.myapp.middleware.globalrequestmiddleware import GlobalRequestMiddleware

# Get the current request object for this thread
request = GlobalRequestMiddleware.get_current_request()

# Access some of its attributes
print 'The current value of session variable "foo" is "%s"' % request.SESSION['foo']
print 'The current user is "%s"' % request.user.username

# Add something to it, which we can use later on
request.some_new_attr = 'some_new_value'
```

...or whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Yep - I was looking for something along these lines.

Comment: @EtaiRaz Okay. I think you managed to confuse a lot of people by using the phrase "request context" which typically has a [different meaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) in Django.

Comment: This answer shoud have a lot more upvotes than this :) It really helps when code gets complex and branched out - and then you suddenly have to use request for something completely different

Comment: after 1.10, Django change the middleware‘s style of writing, detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

Answer (score 5):

You have to write your own ContextProcessor, like explained [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/).

---

EDIT:

After you've created a Context Processor, e.g.,

```
def ip_address_processor(request):
  return {'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']}
```

you can get the variables you need by initializing a RequestContext, like this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def myview(request):
  rc = RequestContext(request)
  rc.get('ip_address')
```

However, please note that if you don't put your Context Processor inside the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple, you have to pass the processor to RequestContext as an argument, e.g.:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def ip_address_processor(request):
  return {'ip_address': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']}

def myview(request):
  rc = RequestContext(request, processors=[ip_address_processor])
  rc.get('ip_address')
```

Some useful links:

- [Django Template API documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/)
- [Settings TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)
- [Django Book: Advanced Templates](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this would allow me to have a variable that is accessible from anywhere in the code (any controller, any internal library, etc.)

Comment: Seems like in this example you are in fact passing around the request as parameter, in order to get the context. This is actually what I am trying to avoid. So far using thread locals seems like it provides the answer to this one (though some claim it is not recommended)

Comment: Your question was specific about the "context" variable, so I provided the appropriate answer. Defining global variables is not the best idea at all, so I suggest you to re-think about your application design, instead of moving forward. You could also use the SETTINGS.py file, if you need some constant values.

Comment: OK, I can see how this can be confusing with the title of my question. However, like I wrote in the question body, I am looking for a way to have a global variable accessible from everywhere, without having to pass it around.
Application design is besides the point. This is a specific need that I have in mind for allowing a log handler to access a global variable. If it's not doable, then it's not doable...

Answer (score 1):

You can still access the current session pretty much anywhere.

Use:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

...
s = SessionStore()
s.session_key # unique_id
s['myvar'] = "something"
s.save()
```

This of course uses the database and the sessions table, so may be a bit too much overhead. Is the variable session-specific, or is it just a global cost?

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

P.S. What I've done in the past is created my own table with a column session_id and various other things, then done the SQL to select data based on session_id manually. Much quicker than using the SessionStore() sugar

Comment: This looks good, if it works, but why does it mean I have to store the session in the database? Can't I use local memory space for it, or memcached?

Comment: Good point, you don't have to use the database if you're using something like memcached. It should work fine with that (I don't have memcached configured on my servers so completely forgot about it for non-persistent storage)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution similar to aya's, using the [modern django way to write middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/middleware/#middleware). I use it to cache some pre-computed stuff in the admin-panels, I would not recommend using this as your cache in your production site.

Define your caching middleware to store any data during the request:

```
class InMemoryRequestCacheMiddleware:
    _threadmap = {}

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.__cache_during_request = {}  # add a cache to the request
        self._threadmap[threading.get_ident()] = request  # keep reference to request
        response = self.get_response(request)
        try:
            del self._threadmap[threading.get_ident()]  # clean up
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return response

    @classmethod
    def get_request_cache(cls):
        return cls._threadmap[threading.get_ident()].__cache_during_request
```

Add it to your middleware classes:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       'myproject.myapp.middleware.InMemoryRequestCacheMiddleware',
)
```

and use it during in your request:

```
def my_request(...):
    cache = InMemoryRequestCacheMiddleware.get_request_cache()
    cache['lifetime'] = 'I will be here until the end of this request'
    ...
```