# Django - code won't enter 'process_request' in custom middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16673949/2880391) example to create custom middleware, though I changed it a little bit. When debugging I see that the code enters that class, and get to the function definition, but it doesn't enter inside the function. I'm using django 1.10.

This is my middleware class

```
class GlobalThreadVarMiddleware(object):
_threadmap = {}

@classmethod
def get_current_data_manager(cls):
    return cls._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager']

def process_request(self, request):
    self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()] = {}
    self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager'] = DataManager()

def process_exception(self, request, exception):
    try:
        del self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]
    except KeyError:
        pass

def process_response(self, request, response):
    try:
        del self._threadmap[_thread.get_ident()]['data_manager']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return response
```

adding to MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

'workflows.api.global_thread_variables_middleware.GlobalThreadVarMiddleware'
 ....
]
```

Comment: Are you using `MIDDLEWARE` or `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, and what is its value?

Comment: I edited the question. Didn't think it's important since the code does get to the middleware class, but doesn't enter the function block

Comment: Django introduced [new-style middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/)   in Django 1.10. The `MIDDLEWARE` setting is for new style middleware, so your old style middleware won't work.