# How to use is_superuser in the django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to override from_db_value in the Field class, I want if the user was a superuser the value will be returned completely otherwise the value has special format.
how can I use is_superuser in this purpose?

```
class Foo(models.CharField):
def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
    if is_superusers:
        return value
    else:
        return "----"
```

Comment: This question is unclear. A field doesn't know anything about a superuser. Why do you want a custom field?

Comment: You do not have the user available here. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633952/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-context-from-everywhere-in-django if you need to access a request globally, then you can query `request.user.is_superuser`

Comment: @schwobaseggl No. Don't do that. Then your model will crash whenever you access it in a place where there is no request: in the shell, in tests, management commands, crons...

Comment: @DanielRoseman Of course, the querying needs to be robust enough to not crash without a request.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Even then, I still wouldn't recommend this. I don't think it's possible to reliably determine what value should be returned when there is no request available, how the to_python function should behave. I think this is opening the door for obfuscated unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: what is your suggestion??

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `from_db_value` doesn't have a context to determine the current user.

Also, you shouldn't. A better way to handle something like this is either through a Model, or their permissions. I'm not sure why you would want an object to have different representations depending on the user retrieving it from the database. It's bad design.